# My app crashes on java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for ID 0x7f0800d2 (JAVA)

Tags: java, android

**Good morning!**

I have here my application crashing on "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException".
When I click on the tabs at the bottom of my application, it crashes with this error there.

I'm actually trying to add OneSignal's PlayerID in the contact tab via a "TextView".

(The PlayerID helps us find users instantly in the database)

**There's something wrong, I can't find it with the other StackOverflow posts.**

I tried to change things around this place, without success.

Code in question:

**Activity:**

```
binding.bottomNavigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener(item -> {

            switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.home:
                    replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.servers:
                    replaceFragment(new ServersFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.info:
                    replaceFragment(new InfoFragment());
                    break;
                case R.id.contact:
                    replaceFragment(new ContactFragment());
                    break;


            }

            OSDeviceState device = OneSignal.getDeviceState();
            String userId = Objects.requireNonNull(device).getUserId();

            TextView OSUserID;
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_contact);
            OSUserID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OSUser);
            OSUserID.setText(userId);

            return true;

        });
```

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/slash_bg"
    tools:context=".ContactFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/contact"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLink_"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:autoLink="email|web"
        android:text="@string/txt_info_1"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/txt_info_recommended"
        android:textColor="#FFEB3B"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="380dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="430dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:autoLink="email"
        android:text="@string/main_mail"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sd_mail"
        android:autoLink="email|web"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="510dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="-128dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/contact"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_contact_support_blue_24"
        tools:ignore="ImageContrastCheck" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonReport"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="290dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/red"
        android:text="@string/buttonReport"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        tools:ignore="TextContrastCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/OSUser" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Which line did it throw the error?

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez 

TextView OSUserID;
            setContentView(R.layout.fragment_contact);
            OSUserID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.OSUser);
            OSUserID.setText(userId);

Comment: setContentView() shouldn't be there in the first place.

Comment: @Lawrence Gimenez What does this sentence mean? Should I put it higher?

Comment: You should only call it once, put it in onCreate(). Not inside the setOnItemSelectedListener

Comment: @LawrenceGimenez I tried to put it on top, but the app crashes as soon as it loads! I may have forgotten to say that there is a webView on it! I leave you with the complete code of the activity, I do not have enough text here so take the link of my site to have access to the file that I have just put online: [https://maybe-ange.com/error.txt](https://maybe-ange.com/error.txt)